# Conditional Join 3 Tables - Difficulty specifying Which Table and Column to return

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements

Working in SQL Server

I have 3 tables

```
[TESTDB].[dbo].[TestList]
[Routing].[dbo].[WUList]
[Routing].[dbo].[WUArea]
```

[TESTDB].[dbo].[TestList] data looks like

```
TestID
1089
41651
1235
6987
51555
71666
```

[Routing].[dbo].[WUList] data looks like

```
TestIDS    AreaPerson1   AreaPerson2    AreaPerson3
01089      TSmith        MBlevins       OMyhead
01099      RJohns        NULL           NULL
03368      RJohns        TPayne         MSmith
45646      TSmith        MBlevins       NULL
55566      NULL          MBlevins       WRestle
77788      ORandy        NULL           LOrdy
02347      MArt          TPayne         MSmith
03333      NULL          NULL           NULL 
04444      NULL          NULL           NULL
```

[Routing].[dbo].[WUArea] data looks like

```
Area AreaPerson1   AreaPerson2    AreaPerson3
01   ORandy        MBlevins       OMyhead
03   RJohns        SNicks         IPfreely
04   RJohns        MBlevins       BFort
07   TSmith        SNicks         BFort
41   MArt          TSmith         WRestle
45   ORandy        ORandy         ORandy        
51   ...           ...            ...
52   ...           ...            ...
71   ...           ...            ...
```

I have been able to join [TestList] to either [UWArea] OR [WUList] how I need the data to appear, but I can't get a 3 lists joined the way I need.

1. Not every TestID appears in [WUList] or [WUArea]
2. If TestID appears in [UWList], not every column contains a value
3. Some TestID appear in [WUList] and each column in [WUList] contain NULL

### End Goal

1. Common Join fields are [TestList].[TestID], [WUList].[TestIDS], and [WUArea].[Area]
2. Return columns [TestID], [AreaPerson1], [AreaPerson2], [AreaPerson3]
3. When joining [TestList] to [WUList], if any of the 'persons' return NULL, join the first **two** digits of [TestID] to [WUArea].[Area] and get the corresponding 'person'
4. **[TestList].[TestID] which are 4 digits in length should have 0 affixed to the LEFT 1st digit when joining to [WUArea].[Area].  [TestID] which are five digits in length can be joined using the LEFT two digits
5. If [TestList].[TestID] does not appear in [WUList] or the Left 2 digits of [TestList].[TestID] do not appear in [WUArea], set [AreaPerson1] = JDoe, [AreaPerson2] = SDoe, [Areaperson3] = TBuck

This one has kept me up at night. Your help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table TestList
(
TestID int
)

insert TestList
values
(1089)
, (41651)
, (1235)
, (6987)
, (51555)
, (71666)
, (01099)
, (03368)
, (45646)
, (55566)
, (77788)
, (02347)
, (03333)
, (04444)

create table WUList
(
TestIDS int,
AreaPerson1 varchar(10)
, AreaPerson2 varchar(10)
, AreaPerson3 varchar(10)
)

insert WUList
values
('01089','TSmith','MBlevins','OMyhead')
, ('01099','RJohns',NULL,NULL)
, ('03368','RJohns','TPayne','MSmith')
, ('45646','TSmith','MBlevins',NULL)
, ('55566',NULL,'MBlevins','WRestle')
, ('77788','ORandy',NULL,'LOrdy')
, ('02347','MArt','TPayne','MSmith')
, ('03333',NULL,NULL,NULL)
, ('04444',NULL,NULL,NULL)

create table WUArea
(
Area varchar(3),
AreaPerson1 varchar(10)
, AreaPerson2 varchar(10)
, AreaPerson3 varchar(10)
)

insert WUArea
values
('01','ORandy','MBlevins','OMyhead')
, ('03','RJohns','SNicks','IPfreely')
, ('04','RJohns','MBlevins','BFort')
, ('07','TSmith','SNicks','BFort')
, ('41','MArt','TSmith','WRestle')
, ('45','ORandy','ORandy','ORandy')

select a.TestID
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'JDoe'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson1,c.AreaPerson1)
    end as AreaPerson1
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'SDoe'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson2,c.AreaPerson2)
    end as AreaPerson2
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'TBuck'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson3,c.AreaPerson3)
    end as AreaPerson3
from TestList a
        left join WUList b on a.TestID = b.TestIDS
        left join WUArea c on '0' + LEFT(a.TestID,1) = c.Area
```

please note: your data sample above in TestList doesn't have enough relating data so i added the TestIDS from the WUList table into the TestList table for more to work with.

i whipped this up pretty quickly so if there are any other variations in your tables' datasets then you will need adjust. thus far, it covers all your basis (at least from what i can understand)

in case you wanted to see more data in the result set to verify that the NULLs are being accounted for, use the statement below.

```
select a.TestID, '0' + LEFT(a.TestID,1) as WUAreaTestID
    , b.AreaPerson1
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'JDoe'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson1,c.AreaPerson1)
    end as AreaPerson1n
    , b.AreaPerson2
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'SDoe'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson2,c.AreaPerson2)
    end as AreaPerson2n
    , b.AreaPerson3
    , case
        when b.TestIDS is null or c.Area is null then 'TBuck'
        else ISNULL(b.AreaPerson3,c.AreaPerson3)
    end as AreaPerson3n
    , c.*
from TestList a
        left join WUList b on a.TestID = b.TestIDS
        left join WUArea c on '0' + LEFT(a.TestID,1) = c.Area
```

---

Comment: Thank you! That is certainly closer than I have managed to get.
[TESTDB].[dbo].[TestList] actually contains 2319 rows of data. When I group by TestID, row count is condensed to 447 rows, which is the desired result. 

This solution produces quote a few more columns than I anticipated

Comment: the TestList table only contains one field, right? so are you saying there are duplicate values in that table wherein when you group by TestID, it condenses down to 447? I'm not following you on this one.

also, the final query statement only produces 4 columns: TestID, AreaPerson1, AreaPerson2, AreaPerson3.

are you running the second query i provided for data proofing instead of the first one?

Comment: Doua, you hit the nail on the head. I was accidentally running the 2nd query instead of the first one when I tested it. THANK YOU!!! 

The TestList table contains more than one column, but I only need to query the values of the first column against the other tables to get my desired result. So sorry for omitting it.

I tweaked the solution to include the needed group by language and its perfect!!!! Answer marked.

Comment: I got ahead of myself. 

It does seem that left join WUArea c on '0' + LEFT(a.TestID,1) = c.Area may not be working as intended.
I've found that in instances where c.[AreaPerson1] or person2, or 3, should be returned, but instead is returning the default value of JDoe, SDoe, or TBuck

Comment: are you saying that your number 5 End Goal above is to qualify each field (AreaPerson1, AreaPerson2, AreaPerson3) individually and not as an entire record? i read that goal as affecting the entire record. for example: in the data above, TestList.TestID value 1235 gets no result when joined with the WUList table (NULL) but does get a result when joined with the WUArea table. you gave an "OR" condition in goal #5 however do you mean for the TestID value of 1235, the query should return AreaPerson1, AreaPerson2, and AreaPerson3 from the WUArea table since it matches?

Comment: You got it, that's exactly what I need. 
Record 1235 would return AreaPerson1,AreaPerson2,AreaPerson3 from WUArea table.

IF there were a match in WUList, it would only return the match and then seek the remaining unmatched values from WUArea.

If there are no matches in either WUList or WUArea, return all default values.

Comment: "This should read "return **the** default value for that AreaPerson"

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer Doua. THANK YOU! I changed the 'or' to 'and'. All seems to be working as I need. I also learned something.

Comment: awesome. glad you figured it out yourself. learning is growing. good luck with future sql queries!